# Where to look for copyrighted names?

Tags: copyright, trademark

We (me and my team) are working on a (software) project and are trying to pick a name
for the group/team.

We have settled on "Watchdogs" (due to the project's nature). However, there is some concern that the name might be copyrighted and might get us in trouble.
I'm aware of the game, however that's called "Watch Dogs" (two separate words).

Where should i start looking for this kind of thing? Like if a name is copyrighted and may get us in trouble or if it's fine to use?

Comment: Figuring out what has intellectual property claims on it is non-trivial. When I apply for a trademark for a client, I hire a professional firm to do a search. It costs on the order of $800-$1500 per mark per category of mark searched.

Comment: @ohwilleke We're not really planning to register the trademark, it's just a name that we picked and plan to use to refer to the team working on the project and are concerned about it being already registered.

Comment: Whether you are wanting to not be sued for infringement, or to register a trademark, the nature of the search is the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will there be any copyright issue if we use an existing product's name?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/42172/will-there-be-any-copyright-issue-if-we-use-an-existing-products-name)

Comment: @Nij It is similar, but still, it just adds to the confusion. What's a "reasonable person"? Is a "reasonable person" likely to confuse a software development team and a video game with a similar name? Does operating in a different software development area than gaming make the situation any different? What's the operating region of a team if it's 100% online business accessible to anyone from anywhere? These question are probably out of scope of the original question, but the more answers/articles i read the more questions i'm having that we're probably better of picking a different name.

Comment: If you don't know what *reasonable person* means, you should search for it, as you should have searched for *name copyright* before asking this.

Comment: I just learned something new! But how would i know how this hypothetical person would react? In my situation, i would expect that a "reasonable person" wouldn't confuse a group of people and a piece of software no matter how similar the names are, because they're almost impossible to confuse when put in context (article, on website, banner, etc. It'll always be clear which is the one being referred to). But this is probably determined on a case-by-case basis, i'm i right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Names cannot be copyrighted at all, in any country.

They can, however, be protected as trademarks.

The general idea is that if one uses a name to identify a product or service, or a creator of products or services, others cannot use the same or a similar name to identify their products or services in such a way that a reasonable person might be confused into thinking that the two came from the same source, or one was endorsed or approved by the other.

Trademarks are limited in scope to a particular country, A name that is protected in Canada, say, will not be protected in the US unless steps have been taken to protect it there.

In some countries a trademark must be officially registered to get any protection, In others, such as the United States, merely using the mark can give a degree of protection, although registration give more protection.

Each country maintains a trademark registry which can be searched for existing marks. There are search firms that will do such searches for a client, and also search for marks in use but not registered, for a fee.

Trademark protection is generally restricted by the type of product or service involved. An anti-virus program, say, called "Guard dog" would probably not interfere with a fantasy game called "Guardog". A private security service of the same name would pretty surely not interfere.

The range of protection depends on how widely known the product is, but "software related" is a very wide area, and except for famous marks, a mark protected in connection with one area of software will not be protected in a very different area of software.

Names that a purely invented, such as Kodak, are more strongly protected than descriptive marks such as "Best Pizza"

Particularly famous names such as "Microsoft" get additional protection even outside their usual areas, so "Microsoft Pizza" might be a problem.

Logos and other graphic marks can also be protected as trademarks, but that is not what the question asked about.

The styling of a trademark, such as a particular font, choice of colors, and so on, can also be protected. This is called "trade dress".

A disclaimer making it clear that a somewhat similar name is not related, and the is no affiliation can help avoid avoid an infringement suit. For example:

> Pear brand kites are in no way associated with, sponsored or approved by the makers of Pear smartphones.

On this site we cannot give specific legal advise, so we cannot evaluate whether a specific proposed trademark would or would not infringe an existing mark.

It might be well to consult an attorney with trademark experiences before finally choosing a name and doing marketing under it.

Comment: @StopUsingCMake Not in all cases, see my expanded answer.
"Software" is a very broad category, and usually trademark protection is limited to a narrower category than that.

Comment: So having a group (unrelated to the gaming industry) named something close to a video game name might not actually be a problem at all?
This is getting more confusing than i thought it would be :/

Comment: @StopUsingCMake This is one of throe cases where the test is what might confuse a "reasonable person" which means there is a case-by-case judgement by a court, with no clear bright lines in advance. To be safer, choose a name not similar to any name currently in use for even a remotely similar product. Note that in the US  if a name is in use, but not registered, and  a similar name is submitted for registration, the registration will often take precedence, that is one of the benefits of registering.. In some countries an unregistered mark is ignored.

Comment: Alright then, i'll talk to the guys to discuss our next steps, possibly picking another name to be on the safe side. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @StopUsingCMake is anyone outside of your team or company ever going to be exposed to this name?  If not then you're  not going to be confusing any consumers.  Furthermore, the owner of the trademark can't sue you if they don't even know you're using the trademark.  For example, if a company has two teams of developers called "Yankees" and "Red Sox," nobody is going to care, even if the teams start playing baseball against one another, unless the company starts using the names in external communications.

Comment: @phoog Yes, unfortunately. If no one would know about the name, we wouldn't have thought twice. The name isn't really meant for any marketing/branding, just putting the people in the team under the same umbrella (referring to the team as "Watchdogs" is easier than "The guys that are working on X"), but i'm pretty sure that's irrelevant to whether it infringes a registered trademark or not.

Comment: @StopUsingCMake whether the name is used for marketing or advertising is **highly** relevant to whether it infringes someone else's trademark. If the name is not used so as to identify a product or the maker of that product to potential customers, or to people at large, in such a way that confusion with an existing mark could well result, then there is no trademark infringement. Only when a name is "used in trade" is trademark infringement a possibility. A purely internal name isn't. An informal but externally used name might be considered used in trade, or might not.

Comment: @StopUsingCMake there are whole companies that use the same name.  You can probably expect that every common term is used somewhere as a trademark by somebody.  If you want to avoid using a word that is someone's trademark because of the mere possibility of infringement, then you are better off randomly generating some words and using the first one that does not exist in any dictionary or trademark database.